# Docker Compose V2 breaking changes - environment file handling issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, compatibility

**[Docker Compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/)** has breaking changes due to which it throws an error (example given below), while parsing environment file.

Example - Apache Druid

Druid's [docker compose](https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/distribution/docker/docker-compose.yml) fails with the below error when using the sample [environment file](https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/distribution/docker/environment).

```
unexpected character "\"" in variable name near "\"druid-datasketches\"
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two potential solutions.

1. Change the environment file by replacing all double quotes with
   single quotes and by wrapping these environment variables with a
   double quote ([example](https://github.com/jansonjc/druid/blob/master/distribution/docker/environment) - works with V2 as well as V1.x)
2. Disable Docker Compose V2 in Docker Preferences > General > Uncheck "Use Docker Compose V2" or by running the command `docker-compose disable-v2`

Comment: Solution 2 does not work `unknown docker command: "compose disable-v2"`